# QueueAsLinkedList Implementation

Tags: java, linked-list, queue, variable-assignment

This is my assignment program in data structure to implement a QueueAsArray. I want someone to guide me about this problem cause I don't have a strong background in java programming.

I'd like someone to give me guidance on what to do to compile and use this code in my main program.

```
public class QueueAsLinkedList extends AbstractContainer implements Queue
{
    protected LinkedList list;

    public QueueAsLinkedList ()
    { list = new LinkedList (); }

    public void purge ()
    {
    list.purge ();
    count = 0;
    }

    public Object getHead ()
    {
    if (count == 0)
        throw new ContainerEmptyException ();
    return list.getFirst ();
    }

    public void enqueue (Object object)
    {
    list.append (object);
    ++count;
    }

    public Object dequeue ()
    {
    if (count == 0)
        throw new ContainerEmptyException ();
    Object result = list.getFirst ();
    list.extract (result);
    --count;
    return result;
    }

    public Enumeration getEnumeration()
    {
        return new Enumeration()
        {
            protected LinkedList.Element position = list.getHead();

            public boolean hasMoreElements()
            {
                return position != null;
            }

            public Object nextElement()
            {
                if (position == null)
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                Object result = position.getDatum();
                position = position.getNext();
                return result;
            }
        };
    }

    protected int compareTo (Comparable object)
    {
        AbstractContainer arg = (AbstractContainer) object;

        long diff = (long) getCount() - (long) arg.getCount();
        if (diff < 0)
            return -1;
        else if (diff > 0)
            return +1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        LinkedList list_object = (LinkedList)object;
        if(list_object.length != this.length) {
            return false;
        }
        Element ptr = this.head;
        Element list_object_ptr = list_object.head;
        for(int i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {          
            if(list_object_ptr.getDatum () != ptr.getDatum ()) {
                return false;
            }
            ptr = ptr.getNext ();
            list_object_ptr = list_object_ptr.getNext ();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: this might help :  [ListQueue class](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/linked-list-based-queue-implementation.html)

Comment: When doing your own comparisons be aware there are utility methods for the tedious if (x<0) {return -1} else if (x>0){return 1} etc. Use java.lang.Double.compare(double, double ) instead.. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion to you is to read the existing LinkedList libraries source something you can easily find. I suggest you also read the source for ArrayList since you will be wrapping an array. Finally have a look at ArrayBlockingQueue because this is a Queue which wraps an array.  This last class is the closest to what you want, but is the most complicated as it is concurrent and thread safe.

When you start writing a class, I suggest you start with something really simple and get that to compile.  Using an IDE, it will show you whether the code will compile as you type the code and suggest corrections.

Then I would write a very simple unit test to test your very simple code. You can do this with just one method. (Some people suggest writing the test case first but I find this very hard unless you have written this sort of class before in which case you are not really writing the unit test first, just the first time for that code base)

Then add a second or third method and tests for those.

When it does something you don't understand, use your debugger to step through the code to see what each line does.

---

I would use an IDE such as Netbeans, Eclipse or IntelliJ CE.  I prefer IntelliJ but Netbeans is perhaps the best for a beginner.

- Download the IDE.
- start a new project.
- create a class and copy and paste the code into that class.
- create another class which uses that class. This is your class.

BTW Did you write the class or was it given to you because it has more than a few unusual coding choices.

---

Comments on the code

- Its a Queue which wraps a class which implements a Queue so delegation appears natural, but it doesn't appear to do this suggesting that `LinkedList` and `Queue` are not the standard LinkedList and Queue which is confusing.
- it uses a field `count` which is not defined instead of the LinkedList.size().
- dequeue accesses the LinkedList twice when once would be more efficient (as the standard library does)
- It supports Enumeration instead of Iterator when Iterator was been the standard since Java 1.2 (1998)
- compareTo is 0 when equals is false which is a bug.
- it doen'ts support generics which the builtin one does.
- compareTo only examines length so a queue with "A" and a queue with "Z" are compareTo == 0
- equals uses `this.head` and `this.length` which are not fields.

Comment: there is a book where i'm going to refer the codes. Yeah some codes are actually unusual. can you guide me on this thing?

Comment: I suspect you are using more than one book because the code is written in more than one style. ;) Added feedback and my suggestions on how to start this program again.